# Create inset window boxshadow border with space between actual window and border

Tags: html, css

I want to create the white border seen in the image below with CSS. White border that is set 25px inside the window. Iv'e tried to use box-shadow inset however was not able to create the space between the edge of the window.

I used this css:

```
border: 3px solid white; //took this out but still no luck    
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px #FFFFFF;
```

I also tried without the normal border as well.

I think I can create an overlay div that has a padding or margin and give it a border, but the problem is the content needs to be scrollable and clickable below it.

The goal: 
The white box just above the icons.

[image]

Comment: As we all benefit of knowing which answer solved a specific question, it would be great if you could accept an answer, if any, that solve your question, or let us know what is missing, so we can find one that does

Answer (score 1):

Use a pseudo element

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.content {
  height: 600px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600/abstract/1) no-repeat center center / cover;
}
.parent:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 25px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works in creating the inset border but I cant scroll the contents. I need to be able to scroll the background.

Comment: the blocks of images behind the inset border. I think i will make that overlay use this method and set pointer-events: none;

Comment: @RickiMoore Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

hope this help.

```css
body{
  background: #000;
}

    .wrapper{
     width: 500px;
     padding: 25px;
     border: 3px solid #CCC;
    }
    .content{
     border: 1px solid #fff;
     padding: 15px;
     color: #fff;
     height: 400px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content">
        this is your content div with white border
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a transparent border to set the shadow where you want it.

The remaining problem is to extend the image to the borders. Use background-origin for this.

```css
.test {
  height: 250px;
  width: 400px;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/600/400);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 50px transparent solid;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 5px cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
</div>
```